# Black toolbar icons error o LibreOffice 5.1

Tags: libreoffice

After installing this new version this problem appeared. It didn't existed in LibreOffice 5.0.4. The only plug-in I have is Zotero.

[image: print screen]

Comment: Under `Tools -> Options -> LibreOffice -> View`, what is the Icon Style setting?  For example on mine it is "Automatic (Tango)."  Also what is the theme setting in  `Tools -> Options -> LibreOffice -> Personalization`?

Comment: Great, Jim! It was the first alternative, mine was set to Automatic (High Constrast). Thank you a lot.

Comment: The menus have all gone dark in the most recent 5.1 and the layout seems glitchy. I had Sifr as the icon style and it was unreadable, dark grey on dark grey. Human or Tango seem to work OK.

Comment: @JimK You should post that as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Turning Jim K's comment into an answer:

> Under `Tools -> Options -> LibreOffice -> View`, what is the Icon Style setting? For example on mine it is "Automatic (Tango)." Also what is the theme setting in `Tools -> Options -> LibreOffice -> Personalization`?